# How to reference Script Arguments in DSC Script Resource

Tags: ms-release-management, dsc

I'm using TFS 2015 Update 2 to create a release. One of my release steps is a "PowerShell on Target Machines" task that I'm using to apply a DSC configuration.

I'd like to use the Script Arguments field to pass in parameters from TFS to the DSC script.

My script looks like this:

```ps1
Param(
  [string]$data
)

configuration ApplyConfig
{
    Script Backup {
        SetScript = {
            #do some stuff with $data
        }

        TestScript = {
            Write-Output "Print param"
            Write-Output $data

            return $true
        }

        GetScript = {
            return @{"Test" = "test data"}
        }
    }
}

ApplyConfig
```

The Script Arguments field contains this:

```
-Destination "$(ApplicationPath)"
```

However, at this point, $data seems to always be null. How can I get the argument defined in the Script Arguments field into my Script Resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you reference $data in the TestScript you need the 'using' scope:

```
TestScript = {
    Write-Output "Print param"
    Write-Output $using:data

   return $true
}
```

The TestScript executes on a different PowerShell context; 'using' allows you to copy the value of $data across those contexts.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation for flexibility is to declare a configuration hash table in your DSC script and pass parameters in to configure it. My [Continuous Delivery with TFS / VSTS – Server Configuration and Application Deployment with Release Management](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-vsts-server-configuration-application-deployment-release-management) blog post has a complete walkthrough of how to use DSC and Release Management in TFS 2015 Update 2.

Getting the parameters in then becomes a case of declaring your parameters as follows:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Position=1)]
  [string]$myFirstParameter,
  [Parameter(Position=2)]
  [string]$mySecondParameter
)
```

and then passing in the value in either directly:

Script Arguments field contains **'myFirstValue' 'mySecondValue'**

or better as variables:

Script Arguments field contains **$(myFirstValue) $(mySecondValue)**

Comment: That's a great article! However, I couldn't get that configuration technique to work until I used the $using prefix from the other answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: For example: Write-Verbose $using:Node.NodeName -Verbose

Comment: You don't use the parameters directly in the DSC configuration - rather you use them via the configuration hash table. My post shows how to do this.

Comment: Indeed, and that's how I'm attempting to do it, but I can't seem to even reference the contents of the hash table without the $using prefix.

Comment: What error message are you getting when you don't use $using?

Comment: The variable ends up being a null value.

Comment: What OS version are you using and what version of DSC? My blog post is based on WS 2012 R2 with WMF 5.0 installed. Are you sure you are using  the exact same syntax as I use in my post? Might be worth copying the web server example and then carefully stripping everything back to just create a folder or similar.

Comment: I believe we have WMF 5.0, but we're on Server 2008 R2. As it is, it works fine now with the $using prefix. I'm not inclined to spend too much trying to exactly match the examples. Thanks!